# SymmetricDS reload channel processing order

Tags: symmetricds

I have two custom channels one of which is a reload channel. How can I configure symmetricds so no data to be transferred on the normal channel until all the initial data is send and processed by the reload channel? In the sym_incoming_batch table I saw that I have many batches send by the reload channel and a few by the normal channel in between the ones send by the reload channel. I think this is the reason why I get some duplicate key error sometimes and since I’m not using the default data loader (I’m using postgres_bulk) I can’t use the fallback logic which would fix this problem.

I tried to prioritize the reload channel by setting processing_order to 1 for the reload channel and 2 for the other channel, but this didn’t work.

Please help me with this. Tell me if you need more information.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I recommend trying configuring all synchronization on "reload" channel. This would order all new db changes after current reload is finished.</strike>

Is it possible to shutdown the application(s) that use(s) the central DB while process of registering and reloading a new node is done?

Comment: How the reload is triggered? Upon node's registration or manually?

Comment: Upon node's registration

Comment: what's the content of `sym_channel` table?

Comment: Shutting down the apps that use the DB is not an option. I think the only solution for now is to use initial.load.delete.first in order to delete the data from the batches that were processed before the reload.

Comment: This may lead to missing data, that has been deleted. No guarantee that the initial load will be bearing the data that is deleted.